# PrestaShop import force to remove old category product

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm working on PrestaShop 1.7.4.2, and I have to import products from CSV file on existing IDs.

The problem is, for the category, instead of override the old value with the new one, it concatenates both...

Do you know how to force PrestaShop to remove the old category value ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be fixed in the new Prestashop version.
If you want to learn more, check the github pull request : https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/pull/10930

Answer (score 0):

First you can update existing categories with same IDs by new names with categories import.

After updating categories you can add these new names in products CSV import.